# MySQL not returning data in Node

Tags: javascript, mysql, npm

I have the following JavaScript that I am executing through Node

```
function afterConnection() {
var query = connection.query("SELECT * FROM playlist;", function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res);
    connection.end();
});
console.log(`The query that ran: ${query.sql}`)
```

}

Pretty basic.  If I execute this code from my Windows 10 machine running MySQL 8 this logs the result set to the console.  If I run this same code on macOS 13.5 running the same version of MySQL the code prints an empty array to the console.  I know that I am connected to MySQL because if I change the query to something entirely invalid (like trying to SELECT from a table that doesn't exist) I get an error back saying the Table is invalid.  So MySQL is consuming the command but isn't sending back a result.  If i run the query directly in MySQL it returns the data I would expect.  I have  double checked my connection strings and there doesn't seem to be any problem there.  Additionally if I run the query directly in Workbench data is returned from there as I would expect.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you ran query on mac directly on mysql terminal?

Comment: The `;` at the end of a query is *only* for interactive shells. It does not belong in SQL run by code.

Comment: Are you sure you connected correctly? Don't just say "or whatever" when it comes to error messages. Please, whenever possible, *post the exact error message*. This not only helps us understand precisely what went wrong, it can steer others to this question that get caught in the same jam. You don't go to a mechanic and say "My car is on fire, or whatever, can you fix it?".

Comment: There is no error message.  What I am saying is if I explicitly write a bad query, SELECT * from playlist2 I get an exception saying that the table doesn't exist.  The 'or whatever' was meant to mean or whatever the relevant error is based on the bad SQL written.  TL;DR:  The code above runs fine unless I introduce invalid SQL to force it to break.